# How to notify android activity on database update

Tags: android, android-activity, android-database

What are the possible ways to notify activity when something chaneged in DB? What is the best practice? Unfortynatelly i cann't find methods comparation with advantages and disadvantages. 
I see the following:

1. Observer pattern with keeping listeners list in Application or DB
   instance.
2. Local broadcast (send on db update and reseive/onReseive in activity)

For example there are two tables which updated by the service or manually by button

1. messages (chat)
2. currency rate (for one currency only)

Chat activity contains list with messages. On update we should add new message/messages in list. Currency rate activity conteins 3 text view: current rate, min rate for today, max rate for today. On db update we should update these values

Comment: More information is needed... What is the DB being used for, how is it being updated, what type of action is required from the activity on update?

Comment: Well, when I asked I meant the common case. For example there are two tables in DB: messages (chat)  and currency rate (for one currency only). Both tables updated by the service operation which run automaticly (cron or push) on manually by button. 
Chat activity contains list with messages. On update we should add new message/messages in list. 
Currency rate activity conteins 3 text view: current rate, min rate for today, max rate for today. On db update we should update these values

Comment: In the typical case you'll have a receiver which will pick up the new information and update your database. You can add code which calls a method within your activity to then update the associated views, lists, etc. One way I've done this in the past (probably not the preferred way) is to create static reference to sub activities within my MainActivity. During the onCreate of a sub class you can then populate the static reference allowing you to then check if it's null and update it from the receiver if it isn't.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "create static reference to sub activities within my MainActivity". As for me it doesn't look like good idea